# Adding multiple styles to same text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, typography, footnotes

Every word of my webpage will have footnotes, and the user will click the word/phrase in order to view the footnotes. However some of the footnotes overlap, i.e. footnote 1 may apply to the current word, while footnote 2 applies to the entire phrase *beginning* with the current word.

Since we live in the future, when the user hovers on a word I want to indicate the range of all relevant footnote(s). Example:

[image]

My background is HTML/CSS/JS, and I am comfortable using CSS to make all that stacking look nice. **It's the HTML itself which I can't figure out, do any of you have ideas for how to stack those SPANs one on top of another?**

Ideally, The raw input shouldn't have a million SPANs all over for tagging...I imagine JS should insert spans based on the word's position in the paragraph. So in the above example, when you hover over the word "score", JS would insert a one-word span beginning at word 2 ("score"), a four-word span beginning at word 1 ("Four"), and a six-word span beginning at word 1 ("Four"). If this is the best method, **How can I tell jQuery that on hover to count words back and forth and add tags?**

Comment: Can you please post you HTML Code

Comment: It's not in HTML yet. I'm trying to plan the best solution.

Comment: You're thinking of an HTML/CSS method for identifying the words/phrases, and that is reasonable. But another approach would be to make each word a part of an array, and then assign look-up values for each member of the array. A single look-up value would lead to information on a word, whereas another look-up value on multiple words would lead to an identification of a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is interesting, but actually quite complex to achieve, so I'll just take your questions one by one.

**It's the HTML itself which I can't figure out, do any of you have ideas for how to stack those SPANs one on top of another?**

spans that are children of other spans will automatically be z-indexed on top of their parents so the html can look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <span>
    <span>
      Four <span>score</span> and seven
    </span> years ago
  </span>
  our fathers...
</div>
```

you can just assign child spans different styles in your css (as you know, adding for completeness):

```
.container span {..}
.container span > span {...}
```

**How can I tell jQuery that on hover to count words back and forth and add tags?**

This part is very difficult. When you mouseover something in javascript, you can get the text of the contents of the element and all sorts of information about the mouse position.

It doesn't make sense to try to calculate the bounding box of the word since each browser, and each os will render text differently, not to mention that non monospaced fonts will have different widths for each character.

Theoretically, it would be possible using a combination of maps and possibly triggering a click (via Selection API) to find out which word was under your cursor, but it probably wouldn't work very well with your ui. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this concept since yesterday and have been able to come up with a preliminary working fiddle - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g3MFt/).

The general idea is to:

1. Put all of the words and associated descriptors in an array.
2. Display the words dynamically.
3. Associate the hidden data with each of the words as they are displayed dynamically.
4. When you hover over a word, the associated data (descriptors at many different levels) are displayed wherever you want them displayed.

JS

```
var mydata = [
              ['four', 'a number', 'four score = 80', 'total of 87 years'],
              ['score', 'a word', 'four score = 80', 'total of 87 years'],
              ['and', 'a word', '', 'total of 87 years'],
              ['seven', 'a number', '', 'total of 87 years'],
              ['years', 'a word', '', 'total of 87 years'],
              ['ago', 'a word', 'ago = in the past', '']
              ];

for(var v=0; v<6; v++)
   {
    $('.holder').append("<div class='num" + v + "'>" + mydata[v][0] + '-' + " </div>");
    $(".num" + v).data( 'dataval1', mydata[v][1] );
    $(".num" + v).data( 'dataval2', mydata[v][2] );
    $(".num" + v).data( 'dataval3', mydata[v][3] );
    }

$('.holder div').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $('.putmehere').html(
                        $( this ).data('dataval1') + "<br />" +
                        $( this ).data('dataval2') + "<br />" +
                        $( this ).data('dataval3') + "<br />"
  );
});
$('.holder div').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('.putmehere').html('');
});
```